# Access to instance not referenced by user code of IDisposable into "using" statement

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this piece of code:

```
using(var a = myFunction()){

    a.Process();

}
```

There is some way to reference not defined instance (`a` in the above sample) into the `using` statement?

I mean, to write some like:

```
using(myFunction()){

    [Reflection?, another stuff?].Process();

}
```

Where `[Reflection?, another stuff?]` should be the equivalent to `a`.

The instance (the value returned by `myFunction()`) exist into the `using` scope, I am sure, because the method `Dispose()` of `IDisposable` is fired properly.

Some clue?

Comment: This reeks of an XY problem. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, if you just want to refer to thinks on the stack.  But I don't think c# works like that.  This isn't _assembler_

Comment: Hi Bradley, I'm writing a piece of code to log some processes and I'm curious about the topic. I know the instance exist into the scope because the Dispose() method is fired, but... it is possible to access to it without declare?

Comment: Unless you mean something like VB6's `With` statement? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx

Comment: @MickyD that's in vb.net as well. I think he does mean using since he has an IDisposable.

Comment: `not defined instance` what does this mean? Is that a translation of anonymous?

Comment: With "not defined instance" I mean: not declared variable associated with the result of myFunction()

Comment: @djv Ah good to know.  Thanks buddy

Comment: Should be "instance not referenced by user code"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the result of `myFunction` you should use it by declaring a variable.

`myFunction` could return `null`. You could define `Process` as an extension method for the type of the return value of `myFunction`. That way you can ignore `null` and not get any null reference exceptions.

Comment: Yes, 100% agree with you Daniel, but, I'm curious to know "where" the result of myFunction() is while it exists into the scope, and if is possible to access it in another way. Thx.

Comment: @SebastiánGuerrero the compiler hides it in a temporary variable.

Comment: So, that temporay variable is out of scope of c# / .Net runtime enviroment?

Comment: @SebastiánGuerrero absolutely not. it just gets tricky and very implementation specific with the generated IL.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could put the last created instance in a static field. I hope you don't want to do this multiple times concurrently.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (myFunction())
    {
        myClass.LastInstance.Process();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
static myClass myFunction()
{
    return new myClass();
}
class myClass : IDisposable
{
    public static myClass LastInstance;
    public myClass() 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("constructor");
        LastInstance = this;
    }
    public void Dispose() { Console.WriteLine("dispose"); }
    public void Process() { Console.WriteLine("process"); }
}
```

Comment: Creative solution!